# scipy.stats.rankdata in reverse direction, maintaining ties and float

Tags: python, scipy

Am using `scipy` `rankdata` to assign ranks. I need to reverse the assigned ranks so that the highest number is given a rank of 1. Have the following working except it doesn't handle ties properly, and returns an int instead of a float. Am assuming it's to do with the loop in `rankdata` but not sure how else to achieve this.

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata
arr = np.array([[10, 15, 19, 8, 8]])
rank = rankdata([-1 * i for i in arr]).astype(float)
```

Given result:

```
[3, 2, 1, 4, 4]
```

Expected result:

```
[3., 2., 1., 4.5, 4.5]
```

Comment: I am getting exactly what your expected result is:

[3.  2.  1.  4.5 4.5]

What version of python, scipy and numpy are you using?

Comment: Just played around. The array I was putting the results into was already cast as int so once I fixed that, it was all good. Thanks for commenting, helped me recheck things

Answer (score 0):

"I need to reverse the assigned ranks so that the highest number is given a rank of 1"

This is the default behaviour of rankdata.

"Have the following working except it doesn't handle ties properly"

The behaviour regarding ties is handled primarily via the method argument. See list of examples below ([source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html)):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rankdata
>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2])
array([ 1. ,  2.5,  4. ,  2.5])
>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2], method='min')
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  2.])
>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2], method='max')
array([ 1.,  3.,  4.,  3.])
>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2], method='dense')
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  2.])
>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2], method='ordinal')
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  3.])
```

"returns an int instead of a float"
I'm not sure how you are getting this.
The only thing I can think of is the note listed in the documentation:
Notes

> All floating point types are converted to numpy.float64 before
>   ranking. This may result in spurious ties if an input array of floats
>   has a wider data type than numpy.float64 (e.g. numpy.float128).